# Java-Convert String to int when using BufferedReader

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

How do you convert a String to int when using BufferedReader?
as far as i remember,its something like below:

```
System.out.println("input a number");

int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine(System.in));
```

but for some reason,its not working.

the error message says:

no suitable method found for `readLine(java.io.InputStream)`

it also says `br.readLine` is not applicable

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? Post the stack trace please

Comment: If you tell what the exactly your problem is then it doubles the chances of getting an answer on SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An `InputStreamReader` needs to be specified in the constructor for the `BufferedReader`.  The `InputStreamReader` turns the byte streams to character streams.  As others have mentioned be cognizant of the exceptions that can be thrown from this piece of code such as an IOException and a NumberFormatException.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("input a number");
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: @Kocko I agree and I'm sure any decent IDE will alert the OP of this.  I was just trying to provide a concise answer, I did update to alert the OP to these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

When using `BufferedReader` you have to take care of the exceptions it may throw. Also, the `Integer.parseInt(String s)` method may throw an `NumberFormatException` if the `String` you're providing cannot be converted to `Integer`.

```
try {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(thisLine);
     Integer parsed = Integer.parseInt(thisLine);
     System.out.println("Parsed integer = " + parsed);
   } 
 } catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("Invalid number");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(System.in);
String a=br.readLine()
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(a);
System.out.println(x);//integer value
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String input = reader.readLine();
 int n=Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   System.out.println("input a number");
try{  
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DataInputStream br=new DataInputStream(System.in);
System.out.println("input a number");
int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine(System.in));
```