# the server displays wrong data

Tags: java, sockets, server

Im writing a client and server and the problem is when is send integers to the server and I want the server to display them I get other numbers than the ones I sent, take in the eye that the other strings work just fine

Do you have an idea why it is happening?

Many thanks in advance! 
**The client**

```
   Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",3333);

    OutputStreamWriter Output= new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    PrintWriter sender= new PrintWriter(Output);
    //creating the hotel by sending to the server the number of rooms
    System.out.println("please enter the number of the rooms");
    String roomsOfTheHotel=scanner.nextLine();
    sender.println(roomsOfTheHotel);
    //providing the information that needed to create a person class
    System.out.println("Enter the first name");
    String fname= scanner.nextLine();
    sender.println(fname);

    System.out.println("Enter the last name");
    String lname= scanner.nextLine();
    sender.println(lname);

    System.out.println("Enter the age");
    String  age= scanner.nextLine();
    sender.println(age);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of days");
    String  numberOfDays= scanner.nextLine();
    sender.println(numberOfDays);

    System.out.println("Enter the roomNumber");
    String roomNumber= scanner.nextLine();
    sender.println(roomNumber);

    Output.flush();
```

**The server**
     ServerSocket serverSocket= new ServerSocket(3333);

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String todaysDate= dateFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println("System is waiting");

    Socket serverSideSocket= serverSocket.accept();


    InputStreamReader input=new  InputStreamReader(serverSideSocket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(input);
  int roomOfTheHotel= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(reader.read()));
    System.out.println(roomOfTheHotel);
    Hotel1 hotel = new Hotel1(roomOfTheHotel);

    String fname= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(fname);

    String lname= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(lname);

    int age = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(reader.read()));
    System.out.println(age);


    int numberOfDays = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(reader.read()));
    System.out.println(numberOfDays);

    int roomNumber = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(reader.read()));
    System.out.println(roomNumber);
```

> ***Example***

**Input**
Enter the age

27

Enter the number of days

4

Enter the roomNumber

3

**Output**

97

115

115

Comment: Do you have any input/output examples?  What kinds of numbers are you putting in and getting out?  What is `reader`?

Comment: Sorry i thought i copied the whole code but i didnt reader is buffered reader

Comment: im sending integers as strings and parsing them from the server

Comment: Did you check on the read() method of BufferedReader? I guess you are using it wrongly, readLine() may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java-Convert String to int when using BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688824/java-convert-string-to-int-when-using-bufferedreader)

Comment: Please add the example input/ output to the question itself and remove it from the comments section.

Comment: It's not a duplicate as I'm not getting any error or exception

Comment: Interestingly, the output 97, 115, and 115, in ascii, is 'a', 's', and 's'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BufferedReader.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) returns a single character (as an int)

To turn this into the correct letter, use `(char)reader.read()`, which can then be put into a String/read to an int - currently if the reader reads '5', [it will give you the number value of it (53)](http://www.asciitable.com/), and you convert that to a String ("53"), and parse that to an int (53 again)

It may be more useful to use [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) (returns a String) to get a full line of input and parse that accordingly

---

`int roomOfTheHotel= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(reader.read()));`

should probably be one of the following:

`int roomOfTheHotel = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());`

`int roomOfTheHotel = Integer.parseInt("" + ((char)reader.read()));`

`int roomOfTheHotel = reader.read() - '0';`

Comment: Thanks I changed it to readLine and it worked, but I still don't understand why the read() didn't' deliver the right integers

Comment: @TheDancerInTheRain it probably did return the right integers, just not the ones you were looking for.  You should also accept the answer so others know the issue is resolved

Comment: No it was supposed to display the same integers I sent to the server and I was getting other numbers. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: @TheDancerInTheRain why do you say it is supposed to return the numbers you inputted?  The numbers are converted to a String and sent through the sockets, then you chose to read the transferred String one byte at a time (ie one char at a time, in numeric form).  If you sent 27, it gets converted to "27", then read as 50 by `.read()`, which is '2' in ascii, another call to `.read()` should return 55, which is '7' in ascii

Comment: Nice explanation thanks! phflack